# Exchange authorization code for token on client or server side

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, authorization, amazon-cognito, serverless

I trying to understand the the Authorization Code flow (currently experimenting with AWS Cognito and the Hosted UI) and there a some ambiguities.

So I am login with my credentials and I getting the authorization code in the URL. Next step would be to catch the code and to exchange the authorization code for the tokens.

1. Where should I do the exchange, on the client side (with Javascript) or on the backend, and then send the tokens as a cookie or in the header? Are there recommendations?
2. I read also on several sources that authorization code is better and more secure than implicit grant. One reason is that the user never sees the tokens. I am not sure how this was meant because as I know, the tokens have to be stored as cookies or in the session/local storage during our session on a website?
3. Where do we refresh our token, client or server side? I guess that the token is not stored in the browser with the access and id_token, but than we have to store it somewhere in the backend maybe and do a mapping afterwards. Are there any recommendations?
4. Do we need the authorization code after the exchange and can we "forgot" about it for our current session?

I am not sure if its relevant, but cognito should be used for a AWS Serverless app (cognito + S3 + API Gateway + Lambda).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to configure Cognito, from there you will get ClientId and IdentityPoolId.
Now to authenticate any user I will suggest to use aws-cognito javascript SDK, [here you can find some examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/code-catalog-javascript-example_code-cognito.html).

After successful login you will get a JWT token, can save that token using

```
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("idToken", idToken);
```

In API Gateway you will find an option to authorize where you have to use Cognito by providing IdentityPoolId/ClientId, this will automatically check for valid token using Cognito, if correct token found then the attached lambda function will be called, otherwise the API will throw an error. If session expires in Cognito then an error will be raised.

Now for subsequent API call use the jwt token as Authorization: header as below

```
    $.ajax({
      method:"GET",
      url: "url here",
      crossDomain: true,
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", idToken);
      },
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks for answer and the effort to write the same, but I am afraid you didn't get the question. I actually know how to set up cognito and the hosted UI, and I am also aware of the authorization of the API gateway, thats not the problem. My questions are related to the approach after I catch the authorization code. If you could help with the 4 questions I wrote, it would be really great. Because I dont have that much developer experience in this area, and I would like get an better understanding of the best practices regarding the handling of the authorization code and the tokens.